# Insert after a string in a file using sed

Tags: string, bash, sed

I want to add some content to the file "file.txt" which is having text

```
"textcolor": [0.9333333333333333, 0.9333333333333333,
0.9254901960784314]}}, "notes": [{"last_modified": "2016-02-
01T16:00:42", "uuid": "2a6063b8-accd-458a-a5ca-18c8c86a6767", 
"body":"\n1. Braggadocio : 1. empty or pretentious boasting. 2. a 
braggart.\n2. Ichor : 1. the rarefied fluid running in the veins of 
gods. 2. a watery acrid discharge from a wound or ulcer.\n
```

I want to add text after "body":" in the file. I was trying

```
sed -i  '/"body":"/a $i. "$var1 $var2\n"' file.txt
```

but nothing happens. Am i wrong somewhere? I am not able to find the solution to this problem. I searched alot on google.

Comment: Are you checking the right spot?  When I try your command I see that it inserts a new line after the line starting with `"body"` that contains the string you specify

Comment: Also, are you using a version of `sed` that supports that `-i` syntax?  That's GNU for sure, I think `BSD` version requires an argument to `-i`, so your command might become the argument

Answer (score 1):

Try this variant:

```
sed --in-place 's/"body":"/"body":"a $i. "$var1 $var2\\n"/g' file.txt
```

This is the the content of `file.txt` after running the `sed` command:

```
"textcolor": [0.9333333333333333, 0.9333333333333333,
0.9254901960784314]}}, "notes": [{"last_modified": "2016-02-
01T16:00:42", "uuid": "2a6063b8-accd-458a-a5ca-18c8c86a6767", 
"body":"a $i. "$var1 $var2\n"\n1. Braggadocio : 1. empty or pretentious     boasting. 2. a 
braggart.\n2. Ichor : 1. the rarefied fluid running in the veins of 
gods. 2. a watery acrid discharge from a wound or ulcer.\n"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

... or even shorter (use the appropriate flag, eg: -i or --in-place):

```
sed 's/"body":"/&a $i. "$var1 $var2\\n"/g' text.txt
```

If you want to substitute $var1 and $var2 with their respective values, you could try the following:

```
$ var1="AAA"
$ var2="BBB"
$ sed "s/\"body\":\"/&a \$i. $var1 $var2\\n/g" text.txt
"textcolor": [0.9333333333333333, 0.9333333333333333,
0.9254901960784314]}}, "notes": [{"last_modified": "2016-02-
01T16:00:42", "uuid": "2a6063b8-accd-458a-a5ca-18c8c86a6767", 
"body":"a $i. AAA BBB
\n1. Braggadocio : 1. empty or pretentious boasting. 2. a 
braggart.\n2. Ichor : 1. the rarefied fluid running in the veins of 
gods. 2. a watery acrid discharge from a wound or ulcer.\n
```

Comment: See if that's what you want. Ideally, please provide the desired output because I'm not 100% clear what you mean.